# Overhauled hubs: still some noise

Tags: hub, mechanical

I've just, for the first time, finished servicing the hubs on my bicycle. They are of the cup & cone type (Shimano). The cones of the front hub where pitted so I got them replaced, along with the bearing balls. The cups still looked smooth. I've packed them with a generous amount of grease and adjusted them for minimal play when out of the fork / no play when the QR is closed.

When I turn the axle by hand it feels smooth. However, with the front wheel installed, when I lift the front and give the wheel a spin, there is some clicking/scratching noise. It only seems to be present when running at a certain speed. My guess is these are the bearings touching each other? Is this normal?

Comment: Did you install the same number of balls? A general rule is one less than the maximum number that will fit. Did you remove all the old grease prior to reassemble?

Comment: Yes, I installed the same number of balls of the same size. I also cleaned all parts thoroughly.

Comment: When you secure the QR, the adjustment on the cones goes in as the axle compresses. When you have the wheel installed, does it spin freely and come to a gentle stop?

Comment: Yes it does. The cone is adjusted following this guide: www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/hub-overhaul-and-adjustment

Comment: @ZulfiqarIII If it is a clicking/scratching noise (as opposed to a clicking/squelching noise from the grease) you might need to tear it apart and clean it again, sadly. It'll still work just fine with the noise (which may go away after a ride or two.)

Comment: Make sure the noise you hear isn't due to the brakes rubbing, or maybe spokes rubbing.

Comment: First just take the wheel off, loosen a locknut, and back off a cone about 1/4 turn.  Then tighten the locknut and try the wheel again.

Comment: Sometimes you get issues with mixing bearings from different batches (odd, but it happens).

Comment: This is very old thread, but I have the same noise from front hub while riding uphill, even on my recording it can be heard: https://youtu.be/WPvHRFzGSC0?t=243. I've cleaned it twice, but sill when I grab the wheel with my hands, rotate it and I still can hear clicking noise from the hub, maybe a new one needed ....

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you've got the cones locked against the lock nuts correctly? I have a front wheel on which it's not possible to tighten the lock nuts against the cones, and as a result it will almost entirely seize after about 5 miles.

Comment: That sounds like a defective hub.